# Specifying JDK in eclipse.ini not being used

Tags: 14.04, java, eclipse, jdk

I've got multiple JDKs on my system (14.04 LTS), JDK 6, 7, 8 - all Oracle. The JDK 8 is the one picked for update-alternatives.

However, the Java project I'm working on requires JDK 7. I've got a separate directory in my home directory with JDK 7 in it. In eclipse.ini I've put in the -vm option specifying the JDK directory in my home. But when Eclipse comes up and I go to check which JDK is in use, it shows /usr/bin/java which resolves to JDK 8.

I've got JAVA_HOME set to a JDK 8 installation, also in my home directory, but that isn't the one shown in the Eclipse configuration. So the environment variable is not how it is selecting the JDK.

Can an expert here explain how Eclipse's configuration is being set?

Thanks.

Les

Answer (score 1):

To specify the JDK in the 'eclipse.ini' you must specify the '-vm' and the path to the JDK **on separate lines**

```
-vm
/path/to/java
```

This entry must also be **before** any '-vmargs' line.

Note: This entry sets the JVM/JDK that eclipse itself uses. You can specify different JDKs for each project by adding the JDKs in the Preferences in the 'Java > Installed JREs' list.